# Trying to download docker on my raspberry pi 4

Tags: docker, installation, sudo

I'm trying to download docker on my raspberry pi 4 but I keep getting the same error.

The error message I get is:

```
W: https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x/dists/buster/InRelease: No system certificates available. Try installing ca-certificates.
W: https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x/dists/buster/Release: No system certificates available. Try installing ca-certificates.
E: The repository 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x buster Release' no longer has a Release file.
```

I don't understand this because I've re-installed ca-certificate but that still doesn't fix it.

(Note: I don't know if this means anything but I also get the same error when I run `sudo apt update`)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I fixed the problem by simple running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates`